# customvision.ai : all projects gone despite showing on the resource

Tags: azure, cloud, microsoft-custom-vision

I have a free-tier azure account.
I have a training/prediction cognitive-vision resource on which I have 2 customivsion.ai projects. I logged-in now just to find that the projects are gone, I also could not create a new project, all while giving me this error that appears on the top right corner of the screen: "Something went wrong. We are working on it!"

If I try to create a new project, I go through all the steps, but then I get the mentioned error.

If I go to settings (from the cog on the top right of [customvision.ai](http://customvision.ai)), I find that my resource has 2 (out of 98 possible) projects allocated. Yet, I can't access them from customvision.ai/projects (they do not appear on the screen).

Trying to access through the API, I get a "Max retries exceeded with url" error.

I could not find a support mail. Instead, I was directed to ask my questions here or on their twitter account via this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/community/. So, here I am.

Would really appreciate any help on regaining access to those projects.

Answer (score 0):

I still do not know what happened. I realize this is not my issue only:
https://github.com/microsoft/Cognitive-CustomVision-Windows/issues/22

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/508b7841-5b0f-4572-9336-52827e9d9e0d/my-projects-on-customvisionai-have-gone-missing?forum=AzureCognitiveService

But it does not seem like there were any helpful solutions to the people who asked earlier.

I used two different PCs using the same connection but I still failed to access the projects.
Weirdly enough, it worked from a friend's PC (and using a different connection).
It has been a really frustrating experience overall and I am glad I will not have to deal with Azure again for some time.